# Extract Data from Multidem array

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, api

I have been trying to extract the following data for each student from a large multidimensional array (Shown further down)

```
Data -> gender,
Data -> grade,
Data -> name -> first,
Data -> name -> last,
Data -> name -> middle,
Data -> student_number,
Data -> ID
```

I have tried various options through searching including Slice, Splice, and a for loop.

Every attempt has been met with failure on all or some of the data. I have never been able to get to the 3rd nested data of First, Middle, and Last name.

How can I take a large multidem array like this, and extract the data listed above in a foreach loop so I can import it into a database? I feel like it is alot simpler than I am making it. I have not included any code as I have yet to have anything that seems remotely useful.

Here is a sample array below. Thanks!

```
       Array
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [data] => Array
                            (
                                [gender] => M
                                [dob] => 7/17/2008
                                [email] => 
                                [grade] => 2
                                [schools] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] =>12345
                                    )

                                [school] => 12345
                                [created] => 2018-04-16T14:01:00.437Z
                                [name] => Array
                                    (
                                        [first] => Jacob
                                        [last] => Smith
                                        [middle] => Rabbitboom
                                    )

                                [location] => Array
                                    (
                                        [zip] => 
                                        [address] => 
                                        [city] => 
                                        [lat] => 
                                        [lon] => 
                                        [state] => 
                                    )

                                [district] => 123456
                                [last_modified] => 2018-04-16T14:01:00.437Z
                                [race] => 
                                [hispanic_ethnicity] => 
                                [graduation_year] => 
                                [student_number] => 1234567
                                [credentials] => Array
                                    (
                                        [district_username] => 
                                    )

                                [id] => 123456
                            )

                        [uri] => 
                    )
  [1] => Array
                    (
                        [data] => Array
                            (
                                [gender] => F
                                [dob] => 7/17/2008
                                [email] => 
                                [grade] => 2
                                [schools] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] =>12346
                                    )

                                [school] => 12345
                                [created] => 2018-04-16T14:01:00.437Z
                                [name] => Array
                                    (
                                        [first] => Jason
                                        [last] => Smith
                                        [middle] => RobesPerrie
                                    )

                                [location] => Array
                                    (
                                        [zip] => 
                                        [address] => 
                                        [city] => 
                                        [lat] => 
                                        [lon] => 
                                        [state] => 
                                    )

                                [district] => 123456
                                [last_modified] => 2018-04-16T14:01:00.437Z
                                [race] => 
                                [hispanic_ethnicity] => 
                                [graduation_year] => 
                                [student_number] => 1234568
                                [credentials] => Array
                                    (
                                        [district_username] => 
                                    )

                                [id] => 123459
                            )

                        [uri] => 
                    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach might be to extract the nested `data` arrays and loop that:

```
foreach(array_column($array['data'], 'data') as $data) {
    echo $data['gender'];
    echo $data['name']['first'];
}
```

If `schools` is variable length then you'll need to loop that or `implode(', ', $data['schools'])`.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if it makes it easier, but im not concerned about any of the data besides the data I listed.

Comment: No, that's pretty easy.

Comment: I tested it and got what I needed. Thank you so much!